# Alipay Integration

Tags: payment, payment-services, alipay

Does anybody know anything about [Alipay](http://market.alipay.com/ospay/aboutAlipay/About_Alipay_&_Alibaba_Group.html) payment service? Does alipay.com have an API (Like paypal or moneybookers)? Does anybody have documentation? I cannot find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any resources to integrate this swift 3? or any swift versions?

Answer (score 15):

I have also started development with alipay. Maybe this can be helpful:
https://globalprod.alipay.com/order/integrationGuide.htm

Comment: This link is to a page in English, which seems better than the currently accepted answer.

Comment: I'd give a golden egg for a tutorial on integrating alipay into a php site.

Comment: this is global. I suppose the question was about local. Global is for "Collect payment for overseas online merchants from Chinese buyers in RMB."

Answer (score 7):

[Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api) has just added [support for Alipay](https://stripe.com/blog/stripe-alipay).  Using this is likely to be far easier than trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me if I can use Stripe to integrate Alipay with Magento. I am in a dilemma whether to go with a paid magento extension or use Stripe services if possible.

Comment: @elembivos This is a Q&A site, not a forum, please ask a new question.  (Although I have no clue about the answer.)

Comment: Well.. If you read into the doc, Alipay is supported only using Checkout from Stripe. Stripe Checkout is a web component, and so you're almost bound to use it on websites. If you think about opening a Webview in a mobile app, they don't support that. So apparently there's no way to let users pay with Alipay on mobile devices using Stripe

Comment: This has now reversed: Stripe no longer supports Alipay using Stripe Checkout (which BTW does support mobile), instead you must use the Sources Stripe API. https://stripe.com/docs/sources/alipay

Answer (score 4):

I just recently needed to integrate Alipay into my site, and decided to open up a derivative of my work. It's pretty basic, doesn't include refunds, etc. But it will hopefully point you in the right direction: https://github.com/bitmash/alipay-api-php

I will improve the library over time (hopefully). Keep in mind this is **not** the GLOBAL Alipay version. It is the domestic Alipay version for Chinese merchants. However, the APIs are very similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hope the link will be useful for somebody.

Comment: Hi, I am new to alipay and wanted to integrate in my project but specifically for chinese merchant this is the link where I had to register https://b.alipay.com/signing/loginHelp.htm
can you please help me understand that how exactly I have to start with.
As in your repo, it is mentioned that its not the GLOBAL, but for domestic Alipay version, but the readme file shows the link of global website, so not sure.
It would be great if you can help me out with the steps to integrate the chinese native alipay and what all I need to do.