# How to integrate Alipay with proper steps in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, payment-gateway, alipay

I have gone through some questions like [Alipay Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282133/alipay-integration)

but none did help me to integrate alipay .Can anyone plz tell how to figure out this Integration in my iOS project.

Answer (score -1):

there are two ways to do this

1. Integrate the Alipay SDK and use Alipay app to do the job.
   SDK download from: https://openhome.alipay.com/doc/docIndex.htm#goto=https://openhome.alipay.com/doc/viewKbDoc.htm?key=236698_261849&type=info
2. Develop a WAP web to pay on web, this is not our job…

also for demo you can look here [Alipay SDK](https://i.alipayobjects.com/e/201310/ALPPassDemo.zip)

> Use Alipay to a complete payment function, we have the following
>   steps: 1) The first contract and pay treasure, obtain business ID
>   (partner) and account ID(seller) (this is mainly in charge of the
>   company) 2) Download a public and private key file (with the
>   corresponding encryption and signature) 3) Download SDK (login pay
>   treasure: /) It provides how to a very detailed document, contract,
>   how to obtain a public and private key, how to call the payment
>   interface. 4) To generate orders information 5) Call to pay treasure
>   to the client, the client by Alipay Alipay secure server dealing 6)
>   Payment after payment to the merchant returned to the client and
>   server.There is a Demo. integrated Alipay function of SDK; the
>   specific mode of operation of integrated payment function, you can
>   refer to the Demo 7) include alipay sdk from above demo link.
>
> ****include this is table view did select row**********
>
> ```
>  1 //
>  2 //The selected commodities call to pay treasure quick pay
>  3 //
>  4 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
>  5 {
>  6     /*
>  7      *Click the get the prodcut instance and initializes the order information
>  8      */
>  9     Product *product = [_products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
> 10     
> 11     /*
> 12      *Parnter and seller only merchant. 
> 13      *The demo parnter and seller information stored in (AlixPayDemo-Info.plist), external merchants can consider stored in
>         *local server or other places. 
> 14      *After signing the contract, pay treasure to be assigned a unique parnter and seller for each merchant. 
> 15      */
> 16     //If the partner and seller data stored in other place, please rewrite the following two lines of code
> 17     NSString *partner = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"Partner"];
> 18     NSString *seller = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"Seller"];
> 19     
> 20     //Partner and seller failed to get, tips
> 21     if ([partner length] == 0 || [seller length] == 0)
> 22     {
> 23         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Prompt"
> 24                                                         message:@"The lack of partner or seller. " 
> 25                                                        delegate:self 
> 26                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Determine" 
> 27                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
> 28         [alert show];
> 29         [alert release];
> 30         return;
> 31     }
> 32     
> 33     /*
> 34      *To generate orders information and signature
> 35      *Because of the limitation of demo, the private key in the 
>         *demo stored in the AlixPayDemo-Info.plist, the external 
>         *merchant can
>         *be stored in local server or other places. 
> 36      */
> 37     //The commodity information gives the AlixPayOrder member
>        //variable
> 38     AlixPayOrder *order = [[AlixPayOrder alloc] init];
> 39     order.partner = partner;
> 40     order.seller = seller;
> 41     order.tradeNO = [self generateTradeNO]; //ID (order shall be formulated by the merchants)
> 42     order.productName = product.subject; //The title of goods
> 43     order.productDescription = product.body; //The description of the goods
> 44     order.amount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",product.price]; //Commodity prices
> 45     order.notifyURL =  @"enter your server url"; //Callback URL
> 46     
> 47     //Application of registered scheme, defined in the
>        //AlixPayDemo-Info.plist URL types, for quick payment after
>        //successful
>        //re arouse the business application
> 48     NSString *appScheme = @"AlixPayDemo"; 
> 49     
> 50     //Product information will be spliced into a string
> 51     NSString *orderSpec = [order description];
> 52     NSLog(@"orderSpec = %@",orderSpec);
> 53     
> 54     //To obtain the private key and the signature of the external
>        //merchant merchant information, according to the situation of
>        //storing private key and the signature, only need to follow
>        //the RSA
>        //signature specification, and the signature string Base64
>        //coding and
>        //UrlEncode
> 55     id<DataSigner> signer = CreateRSADataSigner([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"RSA private key"]);
> 56     NSString *signedString = [signer signString:orderSpec];
> 57     
> 58     //The sign string formatting string for the order, please follow the format
> 59     NSString *orderString = nil;
> 60     if (signedString != nil) {
> 61         orderString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&sign=\"%@\"&sign_type=\"%@\"",
> 62                                  orderSpec, signedString, @"RSA"];
> 63         
> 64         //Fast access to pay a single case and quick call payment interface
> 65         AlixPay * alixpay = [AlixPay shared];
> 66         int ret = [alixpay pay:orderString applicationScheme:appScheme];
> 67         
> 68         if (ret == kSPErrorAlipayClientNotInstalled) {
> 69             UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Prompt" 
> 70                                                                  message:@"You did not install Alipay fast payment, please install. " 
> 71                                                                 delegate:self 
> 72                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Determine" 
> 73                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
> 74             [alertView setTag:123];
> 75             [alertView show];
> 76             [alertView release];
> 77         }
> 78         else if (ret == kSPErrorSignError) {
> 79             NSLog(@"Signature error！");
> 80         }
> 81 
> 82     }
> 83 
> 84     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
> 85 }
> ```
>
> The main integration is the key to the following steps:
>
> ```
> //.Package model order
> AlixPayOrder *order = [[AlixPayOrder alloc] init];
> // To generate orders description
> NSString *orderSpec = [order description];
>
> //The sign of the 2
> id<DataSigner> signer = CreateRSADataSigner(@"The private key key");
> // Incoming order description of signature
> NSString *signedString = [signer signString:orderSpec];
>
>
> //3 generation order string
> NSString *orderString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&sign=\"%@\"&sign_type=\"%@\"",
>                          orderSpec, signedString, @"RSA"];
>
> //The 4 call to the payment interface
> AlixPay * alixpay = [AlixPay shared];
> // appScheme: The first merchant own protocol
> int ret = [alixpay pay:orderString applicationScheme:appScheme];
> ```

From [steps to integrate Alipay](http://www.programering.com/a/MjMzADNwATY.html)